# How to show updated time elapsed since order creation in xamarin list?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a list of Orders. Each order has creation time. Once the users loads the screen the user should be able to see the time elapsed of each order.

Order1   2 minutes

Order2   1 hour 2 minutes

Time elapsed is updating in every 1 minute.

Using timer to load the order list every 1 minute is not good in terms of performance.
Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: You do not need to reload the list every time, you just need to recalculate the elapsed time since the last load

Comment: That means every time I need to iterate items and recalculate the TimeElapsed property.

Comment: Yes.  Iterating your data and doing a basic math operation should not be expensive.